# Why does my dog howl at airplanes?

Tags: dogs, behavior

I noticed that whenever an airplane passes over our house, my dog starts howling and doesn't stop until the plane is a very far distance from our house.

Is this a normal behaviour?

If not what can I do to keep my dog from howling at planes?

Comment: My dog does this and she’s deaf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to [John Cavan's answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/80/why-does-my-dog-howl-at-airplanes/84#84), if you've ruled out any medical problems your dog most likely howls at the plane to make it go away - and it's working!

[image: The power of barking]

If planes pass over your house frequently enough, you'll want to [desensitise](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18/stop-dog-from-barking-at-people-through-fence/79#79) your dog to the noise.

Try searching for airplane noises on YouTube and play them at a volume that your dog is comfortable with. Reward with lots of treats and praise.

Increase the volume in very small steps, as you will undo a lot of the work if you misjudge your dog's limits and he starts howling.

Have lots of patience, it'll likely take a while for your dog to get used to the noise and to associate it with *good things happening*(TM).

Answer (score 4):

He may be finding the engine noise distracting or irritating (same can be said for human reaction too) and so is vocalizing his displeasure as a result. I have to be honest, I don't think I've heard of this before, so it may be worth having his hearing and ears checked to be safe.