# Border Terrier howls at overhead aircraft

Tags: dogs

My wife and I are in our 70's.  Just this year we had to have our 12 year old beloved Labrador Retriever put down due to canine lymphoma. 
My son has an 8 year old Border Terrier who has a problem we would like to help him with.
My son lives on the flight path for a small provincial town airport, and every time an aircraft flies overhead, Cooper howls.  He has done this since he was a puppy apparently.
Last Sunday, I took him over to a small nearby aerodrome used by light aircraft only, and he was fine, even with a small aircraft starting up and taxiing within 10 metres of us, however, when I took him over to the main airport, as soon as a small turbo prop aircraft approached to land, Cooper started howling again.
My son's neighbours are not happy, and we would love to train it out of Cooper if it is not too late.
Other than this issue, he is a lovable family dog. 
Your comments would be gratefully received.

Comment: Hmm. .the range of frequencies that dogs can hear is wider than ours.  Unfortunately gas turbines are VERY noisy and can generate substantial ultrasonic, (to humans), sound.   Smaller engines of that type may be worse than the large turbofans on airliners, (due to higher hp shaft revs), and your dog may even perceive that as painfully loud:(

Comment: I asked on Aviation site, and got: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43153/3264

Answer (score 0):

You can try to desensitize your son's dog to the noise, though after 8 years the behavior may be too deeply ingrained to eliminate.

Your son can find some airplane noises online (try YouTube), and begin playing them at a volume the dog can handle without howling.  Give the dog lots of treats (good ones, like fresh meat or fish) and praise to reward him for remaining quiet.  Spend 5 minutes every day doing this.

Very gradually increase the volume over several separate training sessions, until the dog can handle full volume airplane noises.

Have lots of patience, give the dog lots of treats and praise - it will take some time for the dog's behavior to change.

Comment: You may want to post your answer at the open question https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/80/why-does-my-dog-howl-at-airplanes