# Dog hasn't had friends; how to make new friends?

Tags: dogs, training, aggression, socializing

My 9 year old greyhound-terrier mix has not really ever had long term dog friends that didn't live in the house. We had two dogs for several years, but the other dog wasn't so active, so they didn't really play very much.

When she sees other dogs in the window, she wines to go meet them, but she doesn't know how to become friends right away. When we introduce her to other people's dogs as we are walking or we start chatting with them when they pass our house, it doesn't always go so smoothly. I can understand why the latter would trigger territorial instincts. Sometimes at first it goes ok, but then sometimes turns South. Not always, but sometimes. It has always been brief one-time meetings.

She is really lonely and getting more and more depressed, and I think this will help her, but I don't think she has the social skills yet to go to an unleashed dog park. I really want to get her friends to play with so she is not so depressed, and I want to know how to teach her dog social skills so that she can make new friends at a dog park and not get into fights or show any aggression. Any advice? I am the one in my family taking this initiative, however I am in college and am only going to be home for the month of April and July, so I'd need to do it then.

P.S: for the record, she is not a rescue dog.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to introduce my aggressive dog to other canines?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-to-introduce-my-aggressive-dog-to-other-canines)

Comment: No. 1) She is not a rescue dog so she doesn't have that aggressive past, 2) she is not as aggressive as that dog, 3) he has already had success integrating his dog.

Comment: What exactly is she doing or not doing? You write "it doesn't always go so smoothly" and "She is really lonely and getting more and more depressed" but you never write she *actually* does. She might be far less depressed or agressive than you think, but unless you describe her behavior, we have no chance of helping you

Comment: What works for an agressive dog should also work for a not aggressive one. Maybe you can finish some of the steps recomended in the other question faster with her, because she is not aggressive and not a rescue. But basically you want her to be as calm and nic3 behaving as the other owner wants too :)  My recommendation would be to choose a calm and friendly dog of your neighbourhood to meet regularly so she can build up trust.